# Attaching __author__ to individual classes within module

Tags: python, coding-style

Is it possible to attach an `__author__` attribute to a specific class or method within a module? I am only familiar with the syntax of giving authorial credit for an entire module, but the package I am managing has multiple authors working on different pieces of the same (large) module.

Comment: Why not `import` those different pieces from sub-modules? Alternatively, make `__author__` a string containing all relevant authors (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/9999829/3001761). There's no reason you *couldn't* assign the `__author__` attribute of a class or function, but I don't think it would be *used* by anything.

Answer (score 0):

I personally think having `__author__` on both module or class level is an *unnecessary noise*:

- you have a version control system that already has this kind of information
- if you want to explicitly list the authors - put them into special `AUTHORS` (or `authors.txt`, or `contributors.txt`) file in the project root, see:

  - [What is the format of an authors file for git svn, specifically for special characters like backslash or underscore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159567/what-is-the-format-of-an-authors-file-for-git-svn-specifically-for-special-char)
  - [Django's AUTHORS file](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/AUTHORS)
- or [list the authors in the `setup.py`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9999829/3001761) (if you are making a valid python package)

Related topic with multiple good points about the "authors":

- [Javadoc @author tag good practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269843/javadoc-author-tag-good-practices)